# Rename existing method returning void with input arguments

Tags: c#, extension-methods, streamwriter

Maybe this is silly, but I'm trying to shorten the calling of the method `StreamWriter.WriteLine` becasue I have to call it many times throughout my code. So, instead of calling `myFile.WriteLine()` I would like to write just `myFile.WL()`.

Is this possible?

After searching for a solution I wrote this:

```
private static void WL(this StreamWriter myFile, params string myString)
{
    return (void)myFile.WriteLine(myString);
}
```

but I get the error

> Cannot convert type 'void' to 'void'

Any ideas?

Comment: Try taking out the `return` so looks like just `myFile.WriteLine(myString);` - since `void` just means it doesn't return anything.

Comment: `myFile.WriteLine()` to `myFile.WL` ??? What, really ?? how much this would help ? and  have you thought about readability ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

Comment: OK, OK, I guess the question was silly after all, no need to panic! Still it's useful to know what was wrong with my attempt. Thanks for the answers anyway.

Comment: Please don't do that. Anyone else (including yourself in a few years time) reading your code will likely know what `WriteLine` does and will have no idea what `WL` is. You are making the reader's life difficult just to save yourself a few seconds of effort. The golden rule of good code is "Always prioritise readability over everything". Please don't break this rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Extension method` should only be

```
private static void WL(this StreamWriter myFile, params string myString)
{
    myFile.WriteLine(myString);
}
```

**Reasons:**

- `WriteLine`method of StreamWriter does not return anything i.e. void. It only and I quote `Writes a string followed by a line terminator to the text string or stream`. So you should remove return keyword from the method. Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt(v=vs.90).aspx).

BTW, Extension method should probably be public if you want to use it outside of the class you define it in.

Comment: This is absolutely the answer to the question.  What the OP is doing may be a bad idea, but that doesn't mean a correct answer should be down voted.

Comment: OK, OK, I guess the question was silly after all, no need to panic! Still it's useful to know what was wrong with my attempt. Thanks for the answers anyway

Comment: Well now there is a problem.  Extensions methods can be private.

Comment: @juharr: Yes. But it is advisable to keep them public. It seems OP is a learner and thought to let him stick to basics.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Then you should say that the extension method should probably be public if you want to use it outside of the class you define it in.  It's best to be explicit.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for the extension method, but just for the sake of completeness...

Remove the `return` statement from your method, as it doesn't have to return anything.

```
private static void WL(this StreamWriter myFile, params string myString)
{
    myFile.WriteLine(myString);
}
```

**BUT, Reconsider what you are trying to do**. There is no point in shortening `WriteLine` to `WL`, it doesn't serve any purpose, it will make the code **less readable**, also you will **not be able to cover up** all the [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: OK, OK, I guess the question was silly after all, no need to panic! Still it's useful to know what was wrong with my attempt. Thanks for the answers anyway

Comment: @LeonardoTrivino, you are welcome, one more thing to add, if you are writing extension methods then in most of the cases they should be public,  as they will *probably* be used outside the class.